# Sending basic information over network

Tags: java, sockets

I'm currently working on a game of sorts in which it is necessary for two Clients to communicate with a Server program (I'm writing both Client and Server).  The clients need to be able to send the Server basic integers while the Server needs to send both Strings and more advanced objects.

How should I go about doing this?  My programming knowledge is unfortunately not exactly wide.  I tried using Sockets at first but became slightly confused with them - particularly with how to exactly send or read information from them and fit that into a program.

Comment: What language, what platform?

Comment: Java; I'm doing it using Gridworld Case Study for AP

Comment: Sockets are really not the best option for beginners nowadays. Try some easier web technology like php+mysql+json, you can do that if performance is not critical.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets is not that difficult. A while ago I wrote a P2P chat app., in which I  used TCP   (for sending the mesages) and UDP sockets (for broadcasting, host status, etc.).

The data types used where very basic (later I expanded it to support images), similar to your needs.

You can check the project at source forge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/isytok/

Skip the view classes, and check for NetworkClient and NetworkServer classes in the  network package to start.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think using sockets is fine for your application.  I would take a look at the excellent collection of Java socket examples that are available out there:

- [Client/Server sockets example](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html)
- [Sun/Oracle socket communications docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#server)
- [Simple echo server from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)
- [Simple socket examples](http://darksleep.com/player/SocketExample/)
- [How do I create a client-server socket communication?](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html)

I got those from a google search for 'java socket example`.  There are tons more.

If you have more specific questions then I'd come back with *another* question showing a *concise* code sample, output, and problems you are having.